# A question on the limit of probabilities of random variables with zero mean, based on intuition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume the probability measure $P$ is a **non-atomic measure**. Let $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of real valued, **continuous** random variables so that **$E(X_n)=0 \forall n.$** Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n \ge 0) = 1.$

**Does this mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n \ne 0) = 0\text{?}$**

It just seems intuitively true as $P(X_n < 0), P(X_n > 0)$ both should be in $(0,1),$ as $P$ is non-atomic and $E(X_n)= 0$, hence passing to the limit, I'd expect that if $lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n \ge 0) = 1,$ then the only way it's possible is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n \ne 0) = 0,$$

or equivalently:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n > 0) = 0, \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n < 0) = 0.$$

So intuitively, $X_n$ becomes increasingly concentrated around $0.$ But I'm unable to show it. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd rather use the term "atomless measure" because "non-atomic" sounds too much like "not atomic", and that is not what is meant. And in the context of probability theory, usually the word "discrete" is used rather than "atomic"; a discrete distribution is one made entirely of point masses. The term "continuous distribution" is often taken to mean absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, so there is a density function, but sometimes also may just mean having a continuous c.d.f., which is a weaker condition.

Comment: One way to think about these limiting distribution questions is in terms of a challenge.  If you said, make a distribution that has as little on the left of $0$, and still has $0$ mean.  Since there's no bound on the range of this random variable, I can make it go extremely negative with extremely low probability, and then put the rest of the distribution arbitrarily close to $0$ on the positive side.

Answer (score 2):

The claim isn't true.

On the unit interval $[0,1]$ equipped with Lebesgue measure $P$ define $X_n$ via $$\textstyle X_n(0)=-n(n-1),\quad X_n(\frac1n)=0,\quad X_n(1)=n$$ and piecewise linear in between. (So $X_n$ is a mixture of two uniformly distributed random variables, allocating mass $1-\frac1n$ on the interval $[0,n]$ and mass $\frac1n$ on the much wider interval $[-n(n-1), 0]$.)

Then $X_n$ is continuous (it has a density), with $E(X_n)=0$ and $P(X_n>0)=1-\frac1n$, while $P(X_n\ne0)=1$.

---

EDIT: One way to determine $E(X_n)$ is to derive the density $f_{X_n}(x)$  of $X_n$, and then calculate $$ E(X_n)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X_n}(x)\,dx.$$ Another approach is to recall that $X_n$ is defined on $\Omega=[0,1]$ so its expectation is the integral
$$E(X_n)=\int X_ndP=\int_0^1 X_n(\omega)\,d\omega$$
which can be evaluated as the difference of two triangles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So in your example the sample space is $\Omega := [0,1].$ Could you please be a bit more explicit about the calculation of $EX_n= 0?$ I did a first check and am getting the pdf as: $f_{X_n}(x)= \frac{1}{n^2(n-1)}, -n(n-1) \le x \le 0, $ and $f_{X_n}(x)=\frac{n-1}{n^2}, 0 \le x \le n,$ (by calculating $P(X_n \le x)$ and differentiating). So when I calculate $EX_n,$ I'm getting: $EX_n = \int_{-n(n-1)}^{n}f_{X_n}(x)dx= \frac{n(n-1)}{n^2(n-1)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n-1}{n} = 1 \ne 0.$ Could you state your calculation of $EX_n$ please? Thanks!

Comment: P.S. In order to calculate $P(X_n \le x),$ I first expressed $X_n(t), t \in [0,1]$ as: $X_n(t):= -n(n-1) + n^2(n-1)t, t \in [0, 1/n], X_n(t):= \frac{n(nt-1)}{n-1}, t \in [1/n, 1].$ From here I calculated $P(X_n(t) \le x)$ piecewise for $x,$ as mentioned in the previous, above comment.

Comment: @LearningMath Your cdf is correct, and therefore your pdf is also correct. But to calculate $E(X_n)$ you need $\int xf_{X_n}(x)\,dx$. Your calculation $\int f_{X_n}(x)\,dx$ is verifying that a density always integrates to $1$.

Comment: ah you're right!! I totally for that $x,$ wil recalculate.